# Is it possible to get the initiating contract name from a token transfer?

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.token, transfer

When an external account transfers tokens to my account (which has a contract with an "on_notify" action for incoming transfers), is there any way I can get the name of the contract that they used to initiate the transfer?

In a normal EOS transfer, incoming EOS would be transferred via the eosio.token contract and the transfer action. However, let's say I have a custom token (e.g. AOS) with it's own contract/transfer action copied from eosio.token but is using a contract named "aostoken". Is there any way (from the receiving smart contract) that I can find out the contract name (aostoken) that was used to initiate the transfer?

Example:
`cleos push action eosio.token transfer '[ "fromaccount", "toaccount", "1.0000 EOS", "memo" ]'`

Alternate push action
`cleos push action aostoken transfer '[ "fromaccount", "toaccount", "1.0000 AOS", "memo" ]'`

If I have an "on_notify" action on my smart contract that's connected to the "toaccount", is there any ways to access the `aostoken` contract name from the transfer action?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_first_receiver()` to get the name of the contract from where the notification comes.